# IO.copy_stream is not copying file which is read from S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model `Report` to export all the Pdf attachments done for the bills. I have other models `Bill`, `Upload`.

`Bill has many uploads`

##### Tech Stack used

Ruby 2.5.8
Rails 5.0.7

##### Dummy Code

```
  require 'fileutils'
  require 'zip'
  require 'open-uri'

  class Report < ApplicationRecord
    main_dir = "tmp/Attachment-#{self.id}"

    FileUtils::mkdir_p main_dir

    bills.each do |bill|
      bill_directory_name = 'Bill_#{bill.id}'

      bill.uploads.each do |bill_upload|
        begin
          FileUtils::cd main_dir do
            FileUtils::mkdir_p "#{bill_directory_name}"

            file = open(bill_upload.file.url, 'rb')

            upload_name = "Invoice-#{bill_upload.file_file_name}-#{bill_upload.id}"
            FileUtils::cd "#{bill_directory_name}" do
              IO.copy_stream(file, "#{upload_name}")
            end
          end
        rescue => exp
          Airbrake.notify(exp)
        end
      end
    end

    path = "tmp/Attachment-#{self.id}"
    archive = File.join(path, "Attachment-#{self.id}" + '.zip')
    FileUtils.rm archive, force: true

    Zip::File::open(archive, 'w') do |zipfile|
      Dir["#{path}/**/**"].reject{|f| f==archive }.each do |file|
        zipfile.add(file.sub(path + '/', ''), file)
      end
    end
  end
```

Zip folder is created successfully. When I extract zip folder, I can see there are many sub folders created for bills. Each bill folder have uploaded PDF files as well and it's working.

##### Problem

Most of the time exported bill sub-directory contains PDF uploaded file. But, rarely sometime (once in a 100's of iteration), when I export report, I cannot see PDF file inside some of the bill sub directory. I have added error handling but there is no error generated. So, it's hard to reproduce this issue at my end.

How to confirm that this file copy command is successful `IO.copy_stream()`?

Please check dummy code and provide your feedback if I need to improve or modify any line of code?

```
file = open(bill_upload.file.url, 'rb') # File is read from S3

upload_name = "Invoice-#{bill_upload.file_file_name}-#{bill_upload.id}"

FileUtils::cd "#{bill_directory_name}" do
  IO.copy_stream(file, "#{upload_name}")
end
```

Any help would be appreciated.